# How is it possible to limit download speed?

Tags: algorithm, web-applications, methods, download

Lately I've asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738706/how-to-limit-an-upload-speed-in-java-servlet) question. But the answer doesn't suit my demands, and I know that file hosting providers do manage to limit the speed. So I'm wondering what's the general algorithm/method to do that (I do mean **downloading** technique) - in particular limiting single connection/user download speed.

@back2dos I want to give a particular user a particular download speed (corresponding to hardware capabilities of course) or in other words give user ability to download some particular file with lets say 20kb/s. Surely I want to have an ability to change that to some other value.

Comment: you need to be more specific. what is the scenario? who's download speed do you want to limit? that of a specific user, or actually the overall upload of the server? why do you want to limit speed? etc.

Comment: @back2dos I think that "why.." part is irrelevant and will not help anyhow. Concerning scenario - that's what I'm asking for out here :).

Comment: ok, "why" is partially irrelevant. the question is: what are you trying to accomplish, what is your current problem and what is the desired solution? and what means do you see fit? what server are you using? without being you being more specific, I'd say the easiest way is to host your server in new zealand :P so for the sake of sensible answer, could you at least be so kind as to say what web server you're using? and what "limit" means? do you want an even distribution between users? does it have to be HTTP? and so on.

Comment: @back2dos That's a general question, I'm not talking about some particular platform or something, I'm looking for a general description of how it's done (or how people do it). If you know how it may be done through HTTP or may be you know how to make use of sockets - you're welcome, while those suggestions don't repeat other answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a token bucket ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket)

Comment: Yes, though the token bucket allows for bursts.  You can also use a token buck in a hierarchical setup easily and cleanly (you could probably use a leaky bucket in a hierarchy,too, but the hard limit of the leaky bucket, IMHO, complicates that).

Answer (score 4):

Without mention of platform/language, it's difficult to answer, but a "leaky bucket" algorithm would probably be the best fit:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket

Answer (score 0):

Well, since this answer is really general, here's a very simple approach for plain TCP:

You put the resource handlers of all download connection into a list, paired up with information about what data is requested, and loop through it. Then you write a chunk of the required data onto the socket, maybe about 1.5K, which is the most commonly used maximum segment size, as far as I know. When you're at the and of the list, you start over. Before starting over, simply wait to get the desired average bandwidth.

Please note, if too many clients have lower bandwidth than you allow, then your TCP buffer is likely explode. some TCP bindings permit finding the size of currently buffered data for one socket. if it exceeds a threshold, you can simply skip the socket.

Also, if too many clients are connected, you will actually not have enough time to write to all the sockets, thus after one loop, you "have to wait for a negative time". Increasing the chunk size might speed up things in such scenarios, but at some point your server will stop getting faster.

A more simple approach is to do this on the client side, but this may generate a lot of overhead. The dead simple idea is to have the client request 1K every 50ms (assuming you want 20KB/s). You can even do that over HTTP, although I strongly suggest bigger chunk size, since HTTP has enourmous overheads.

My guess is, the best is to try to find a webserver capable of doing such things out of the box. I think Apache has a number of modules for al kinds of quota.

greetz
back2dos